# Heroku NodeJS - Error: Cannot find module './prod.json'

Tags: json, node.js, heroku

First time pushing this app to heroku (and first time doing a NodeJS API), and when the app tries to start, I get this error in heroku's logs. It works fine in dev - what am I missing?

I have a file: `config/prod.json`

And in package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "export NODE_ENV=prod && nodemon ./index.js",
    "windev": "set NODE_ENV=dev && nodemon ./index.js",
    "dev": "export NODE_ENV=dev && nodemon ./index.js",
    "prod": "export NODE_ENV=prod && nodemon ./index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
```

Full output:

```
2018-01-05T21:40:37.628592+00:00 app[web.1]: > export NODE_ENV=prod && nodemon ./index.js
2018-01-05T21:40:37.628593+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-01-05T21:40:39.610679+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] 1.12.5
2018-01-05T21:40:39.620087+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
2018-01-05T21:40:39.620443+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] watching: *.*
2018-01-05T21:40:39.621169+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] starting `node ./index.js`
2018-01-05T21:40:42.769518+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:540
2018-01-05T21:40:42.769527+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2018-01-05T21:40:42.769528+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
2018-01-05T21:40:42.769528+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-01-05T21:40:42.769529+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module './prod.json'
2018-01-05T21:40:42.769555+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
2018-01-05T21:40:42.769553+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
2018-01-05T21:40:42.769554+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
2018-01-05T21:40:42.769559+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
2018-01-05T21:40:42.769556+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/config/config.js:2:18)
2018-01-05T21:40:42.769556+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
2018-01-05T21:40:42.769560+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
2018-01-05T21:40:42.769560+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
2018-01-05T21:40:42.769561+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
2018-01-05T21:40:42.769561+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
2018-01-05T21:40:42.769563+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
2018-01-05T21:40:42.769563+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
2018-01-05T21:40:42.769564+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:6:16)
2018-01-05T21:40:42.769565+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
2018-01-05T21:40:42.769565+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
2018-01-05T21:40:42.769566+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
2018-01-05T21:40:42.769568+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
2018-01-05T21:40:42.769569+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
2018-01-05T21:40:42.769570+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
2018-01-05T21:40:42.769571+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
2018-01-05T21:40:42.769572+00:00 app[web.1]:     at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
2018-01-05T21:40:42.827358+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```